# HandlerThread and Handler: how to use AudioRecord.setRecordPositionUpdateListener?

Tags: android, multithreading, handler, audiorecord, android-handlerthread

I'm confused by `Handler` and `HandlerThread` classes usage. The reason I'm trying to use them is I want to utilize `AudioRecord` class and its `setRecordPositionUpdateListener` method ([reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord.html#setRecordPositionUpdateListener%28android.media.AudioRecord.OnRecordPositionUpdateListener,%20android.os.Handler%29)). The methos description says:

> Use this method to receive AudioRecord events in the Handler associated with another thread than the one in which you created the AudioTrack instance.

And that's exactly what I want - to setup the `AudioRecord` in the main thread, but receive data in a working thread. I figure I need a `HandlerThread` so I've created and started one. I've also defined a callback method that implements `AudioRecord.OnRecordPositionUpdateListener` interface. I want this callback to be called from the worker `HandlerThread`. What I don't understand now is how to create the `Handler` to pass to `setRecordPositionUpdateListener`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To associate `Handler` with a certain thread, you should create it by passing corresponding `Looper` in its [constructor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#Handler%28android.os.Looper%29). So, if you already have a `HandlerThread` it can be done in the following way:

```
Looper looper = myHandlerThread.getLooper();
Handler handler = new Handler(looper);
```

And that's it, just use this handler in `setRecordPositionUpdateListener` method and callback will be executed at the worker thread. If you need more explanation on `Handler`, `Looper` and `HandlerThread`, you can take a look [here](http://blog.nikitaog.me/2014/10/11/android-looper-handler-handlerthread-i/).

Comment: Simple indeed! I was just looking through `Handler` documentation and it appeared to me that I must implement some of its methods to create a `Handler` instance, i. e. I somehow thought it's an interface. Thanks for the clarification.